Can a person with an Indian passport transit from Tbilisi through Amsterdam the my way to the USA?
I'm an Indian passport holder travelling from Tbilisi back to the USA. I have a visa for the US and will get a visa on arrival in Georgia.
I was thinking of booking a flight but all the flights transit through a European Country (eg. flying through Amsterdam). Do I need to get a European visa or transit visa to fly back?

'Transit through an European country' is very broad. If you want a reasonable answer, you will have to tell where you are going to transit and not just 'eg. Amsterdam'.
